# MSAL not working with Xamarin.Forms when deployed to Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create a simple application that uses Azure AD B2C Authentication using the latest version of Xamarin Forms. I'm on Windows 10 Pro using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition 15.5.2. I've followed the [Installing Xamarin on Visual Studio in Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/windows/) setup guide. I created a brand new "Cross-Platform" Xamarin Forms application, and I've successfully gotten the template application to render on the bult-in Android emulator, an iOS emulator after configuring my Mac Mini, and Xamarin Live Player after I signed up for the TestFlight beta.

Next, I started to try and implement Azure AD B2C Authentication. I read [Integrate Azure AD B2C into a Xamarin forms app using MSAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/), and tried to make modifications to my application based on what I saw in the guide. Here is where I'm running into trouble. Whenever I make a call to `AcquireTokenAsync` from within the function that handles the sign in button click, it hangs for a few seconds and then fails with the following error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   startActivity(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.companyname.MobileClient-1/base.apk)

Just to make sure it wasn't something I messed up in Azure, I did clone the sample GitHub project referenced in the MSAL guide above, followed the steps to modify the code, and verified that it does work as expected against all of my Azure resources.

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out with no success. I've compared the sample project and my new project side-by-side and noticed a number of differences, but trying to reconcile the two has either failed completely or resulted in no progress. A few things that jump out at me that *might* be an issue:

- The MSAL sample solution  has has it's main project listed with (Portable) in solution explorer. Mine does not. It's using .NET Standard. I don't even see a way in Visual Studio to make a Portable project anymore.
- The MSAL sample solution uses Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.224. My solution is using the latest version. Downgrading to that version didn't do anything though.
- The Android specific MainActivity class in the MSAL sample solution inherits from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity`. My Android specific MainActivity class inherits from  `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity`. I tried switching mine over, but I kept running into issues that I couldn't resolve. I honestly don't even understand the difference after trying to read up on it.
- The MSAL sample soluiton has no warnings. Right out of the box, with no tinkering, my solution has over 20. They include things like:

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0)
>   is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1).
>   You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your
>   project.
>
> Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 23.3.0 requires
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0) but version
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 was resolved.
>
> MobileClient.Droid.Resource.Color.hint_foreground_material_light.
>   Please check that your Nuget Package versions are
>   compatible.

I'm really not sure where to go at this point. I'm moving along by simply continuing to add more stuff into my copy of the MSAL sample solution... but I am concerned about how far "behind" the sample is from the current state. I don't want to couple my solution to outdated or obsolete mechanisms straight from the get-go.

Edit: I'm now fairly certain it's something to do with the Android Emulator. I've been able to push the same Xamarin application to my actual iPhone and everything seems to work. I don't have an actual Android device to test with, though.

Edit #2: I've used the SDK manager and installed everything that had an available update. That has not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not the emulator, though you cant use MSAL to authenticate on emulators that don’t have the chrome browser installed.

The first problem you mention is probably due to having this missing from the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        var state = BaseApplication.ApplicationState;
        bool test = true;
    }
```

The second problem is due to a difference in what forms expects as the android build target and what you have selected. Select the latest Android under the Build tab in the project properties.

The third problem is a NuGet version reference conflict. The MSAL NuGet definition has an error in it that the MSL dev team seem reluctant to rectify. It references an exact (=) version of Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, insteas of greater than or equal (>=). Try this:

Try to add the MSAL NuGet package. Note the conflicting versions. 
Unload the solution from VS.
Open the xxx.Android.csproj file. Find the ItemGroup with

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version=" " />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version=" " />
```

Manually add in the following dependencies (replacing the X.y.z with the version NuGet reports as required by MSAL):

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" Version="X.y.z" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" Version=" X.y.z" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" Version=" X.y.z" />
```

Load solution and build. Now you should be able to successfully add the MSAL NuGet package and successfully build the solution.

Unload the solution again and manually edit the xxx.Android.csproj file, this time change the three references back to the versions referenced by Xamarin.Forms. Reload and rebuild.

This should resolve the NuGet version conflicts.

The last problem you list might be a dependency on the AppCompat which provides a lot of resources.